# How to make a dynamic storage of objects (c++)

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am a beginner to programming and I am trying to find a way to create a dynamic storage of objects of my pigeon class. Here is my code:

```
class pigeon {
public:
    pigeon(std::string nameI);
    void outputInfo();
private:
    std::string name;
};
```

The idea is that I want to be able to add a new object, have a place to store its information, then be able to add another object, and so on. I have no idea where to start with this or even what data structure to use, I have no experience storing objects.

Comment: Are the objects you want to store of the same type? If so you can simply use a `std::vector<YourObject>`

Comment: [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: You need to indicate in your question what you mean by *store*. Do you mean in memory or something more permanent?

Comment: As @FrançoisAndrieux already said. Use a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already pointed out in the comments, you should preferably use a container that handles its resources following the [RAII/RDID-idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) ( "Resource Acquisition Is Initialisation" / "Resource Destruction is Deletion") so you don't have to worry about it yourself. This is also a simple way of preventing resource leaks when an exception is thrown.

One of the commonly used containers of the C++ standard library is [`std::vector<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

You'd use it like this (just to give you an initial idea, please refer to the documentation for further explanation and examples):

```
#include <vector>

// ...

{
    std::vector<pigeon> pigeons;

    pigeons.push_back("Karl");   // add three pigeons
    pigeons.push_back("Franz");  // at the end of the
    pigeons.push_back("Xaver");  // vector

    pigeons[1]; // access "Franz"

    for(auto /* maybe const */ &p : pigeons) {  // iterate over the vector
        // do something with pigeon p
    }

} // pigeons goes out of scope, its destructor is called which
  // takes care of deallocating the memory used by the vector.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make vector with pointer of your class:

```
std::vector<pigeon*> pigeons;
```

Then allocate new pigeon object and push it into your vector:

```
pigeon * pig = new pigeon("pigeon");
pigeons.push_back(pig);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you suggest using raw owning pointers and adding another level of indirection where `std::vector<pigeon>` already does what the OP wants?

Comment: Op wants to store dynamic objects. When you use vector<pigeon> it first copies the object and stores it. This is not dynamic storing. And some point of view it is not efficient.

Comment: There is always [emplace_back()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) and smart pointers.

Comment: Can you give an example of usage of these?

Comment: `pigeons.emplace_back()` with arguments that match a constructor of `pigeon` will construct the element to insert into the vector in-place directly in the memory managed by the vector. No temporaries, no copying.

Comment: C++ isn't a high-level language like C# or Java. It has pointers and, it uses pointers. Seeing pointers and references in C++ something that you can't avoid.

Comment: Yes, there are reasons for using raw pointers that \*don't\* own the resources they point to. There is no reason however to use raw resource owning pointers since C++11. You earlier tried to argue with efficiency (*And some point of view it is not efficient.*). However adding another layer of indirection and scattering the pigeons throughout the memory instead of keeping them in a consecutive memory area for no real reason will deteriorate performance, not enhance it.

Comment: I am student actually not C++ expert of course. But I thought it is efficient because assume you have two of 1 Gb objects and you want to change the order of the objects. Vector without pointers you should rewrite the minimum 2gb of data. With pointers you should just rewrite some bytes. This is my opinion, of course, I prefer using pointers.

Comment: If copying objects is very expensive, don't copy. There are better ways like having a collection of indexes around that you reorder instead of the objects in the vector. Maybe use a `std::list<std::unique_ptr<pigeon>>`.